# removing values of unchecked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have following code which generates a checkbox dynamically and on selection its value in assigned to a variable.
The problem i'm facing is that I do not know how to remove the value from the variable once the checkbox is unchecked.

```
function getCheckBox(contentItem) {
        var checkbox = $("<input type='checkbox'/>");
        checkbox.css("height", "20");
        checkbox.css("width", "20");

        checkbox.change(function () {
            var checked = checkbox[0].checked;

            $(':checkbox').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                {
                    contentItem.value.details.checked = true;
                    global_audit_team = global_audit_team + contentItem.value.Name + ",";
                    alert(global_audit_team);
                }

                else
                {
                    contentItem.value.details.checked = false;
                    alert(contentItem.value.Name + " unchecked");
                }
            });


        });
        return checkbox;
    };
```

Comment: can you create http://jsfiddle.net for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g6e0vor2/1/?

Comment: @jitthakore If your problem solved and my answer were useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple `JQuery` code.

```js
var checkedCheckbox = "";
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () { 
    var name = $(this).attr("name") + ",";
    if ($(this).prop("checked"))
        checkedCheckbox += name;
    else
        checkedCheckbox = checkedCheckbox.replace(name, "");   
    $("span").text(checkedCheckbox);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="A"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="B"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="C"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="D"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="E"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="F"/>
<span></span>
```